# calcular promedio y porcentajes en javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, math

que tal necesito un poco de ayuda, tengo el siguiente arreglo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito es transformar `quantity` en % , correspondiente al promedio total de todas las cantidades, es decir:

la suma total de `quantity` es 791 que equivale al 100%

entonces 656 correspondería a 83%, 31 correspondería a 4% y así sucesivamente hasta tener todos los % en el mismo arreglo,

```
- Sumar todo para obtener cada %
- Multiplicar el numero x 100 y divido por la suma total
```

¿Como lo aplicarían con menor código posible en javascript?

Tengo el siguiente código, pero no me da lo que quiero.

```
totalLocation = 0;

firstsix.forEach(element => {
  totalLocation = totalLocation + element.quantity;
  console.log(element.quantity * 100 / totalLocation)

  })
```

Comment: Me parece eso no es un arreglo sino un objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No funcionará, porque el proceso que deseas realizar se debe separar en dos pasos bien definidos, primero debes calcular el total de las cantidad del `array` de objetos que tienes.

Para posteriormente sacar su aproximación en % de acuerdo a ese total. No funciona actualmente porque `totalLocation` solo en la última iteración tendrá el total correcto, en las iteraciones anteriores no.

```js
var firstsix = [{quantity :656},{quantity :31},{quantity :28},{quantity :28},{quantity :25},{quantity :23}];
var totalLocation = 0;
firstsix.forEach(element => {
  totalLocation += element.quantity;
})
firstsix.forEach(element => {
 console.log(element.quantity * 100 / totalLocation)
})
// O en un sola línea
//firstsix.forEach(element => totalLocation += element.quantity);
//firstsix.forEach(element => console.log(element.quantity * 100 / totalLocation));
```